# Meteor.js: Run processes at select ISO timestamps

Tags: meteor

I have a Mongo DB (hooked up to my Meteor app) with different tasks and ISO timestamps of when each task should be performed. Once a task gets performed, it gets purged from the table.

Using Meteor.js, how can I incorporate such a feature? In my table I have: "task1: timestamp1; task2: timestamp2; task3: timestamp3;" and so on. I want each task to be performed at the appropriate time, and then be purged from the table because new tasks get added to that table constantly.

What kind of scheduler can I use to make this possible? I tried using this: https://atmospherejs.com/percolatestudio/synced-cron - but that seems like it's more designed for repetitive processes.

I was thinking something along the lines of this approach: using the library above (the percolatestudio synced-cron library), every minute, check the current timestamp with ALL of the timestamps in the database table; and if any timestamps match, then run that task, and purge that document from the table. Do you guys think this approach would work? What would happen if my server is running in the US, but the timestamp was scheduled in Japan? If I convert my current system time to ISO, it won't be the same as the timestamp from the db...

Any hints appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use synced-cron at work in our Meteor app and I'm quite happy with it. I would convert the timestamps to GMT and record what the original time zone was. I think you are on the right track.